# How to handle circular dependency between User and Auth modules?

Tags: architecture, nest, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency in my app between UserModule and AuthModule.

AuthModule contains AuthGuard class which uses UserService (UserService.findOne) to check user existence and in positive case - let him through.
AuthModule also UserService for the user creation process.

At the same time UserModule imports AuthModule as for UserController we need to use AuthGuard to prevent the user from accessing routes that are not intended for him.

I understand that it's a kinda classic problem, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any well-reasoned solutions for this.

- somebody just put this AuthGuard into the UserModule
- somebody duplicates code from "UserService.findOne" method in AuthGuard
- somebody recommends using "forwardRef" functionality (in the case of nestjs)

Which approach is the most suitable in this case? Because as per my understanding, "forwardRef is definitely not the best way of handling this problem.

```js
UserModule: 
  class UserService {
    isEligible = async (userId: string) => {
      // ... check if the user is existing
      // ... check if user is not banned
    }
    
    create = async (data) => { ... }
  }
  
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  class UserController {
    // ... guard should be applied for all user routes
  }
 
// ------------------------------------------------ 

AuthModule:
  class AuthGuard {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) [} 
  
    check = async (request): Promise<boolean> => {
      return this.userService.isEligible(request.body.userId);
    }
  }
  
  class AuthService {
    authenticate = async (data) => {
      await this.userService.create(data);
      // ... this method depending on "data" creates new user
      // or return data of existing
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another approach.

It seems that both services need to do some 'Auth', but it's not the same 'Auth' :) The AuthModule does ***Authentication*** while the UserService deals with ***Authorization***. From  [Okta](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/authentication-vs-authorization/#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20authentication,permission%20to%20access%20a%20resource.): *Authentication confirms that users are who they say they are. Authorization gives those users permission to access a resource* .

So, how about the AuthModule calls the UserService in order to ***authenticate***, and returns some access token as a response which represents the permissions of this user. Then - the user can call the UserService with this access token as a header, and ***authorization*** is done within the UserService with this token, such that no need to call AuthModule.

With this approach, the AuthModule is called only once at the beginning by the user, and then calls to UserService (by the user as well) are done with the access token which embodies his/her permissions. I believe this will also cause performance improvement since no need to call the authentication service every time.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot here to mention that I also have AuthService, and I use it to "autenticate" user (code example attached), so it increases coupling a bit.

Comment: Still standing with the above :) I believe the healthy flow here is: call AuthService for authentication and get some access token -> call UserService with this access token for routes authorization, instead of calling AuthModule from UserService for that.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that your main idea (in the case of using AuthGuard) is to treat AuthGuard as code related directly to UserService?

Comment: Not exactly, I suggest there will be 2 separated services - (1) AuthService (2) UserService. In order to call UserService, you must provide a header with an access token which embodies the permissions you're entitled to. This access token is retrieved from AuthService (which calls UserService to do the authentication). So the client needs to authenticate first agains AuthService, and then take the access token and use it for calling UserService to prevent the user from accessing routes that are not intended for him.

Comment: Such that AuthService calls UserService, but not the opposite, and you avoid the circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> At the same time UserModule imports AuthModule as for UserController we need to use AuthGuard to prevent the user from accessing routes that are not intended for him.

To be honest I don't understand the reasoning here.  Without seeing actual code it is hard to tell, but usual approach would be to inject both `AuthModule` and `UserModule` into `UserController` and remove the dependency of `UserModule` on `AuthModule` (and move appropriate logic to the `AuthModule`).

Comment: I've added an example of code to my question.

Comment: @eugenedrvnk personally I would place services in separate modules.